# Parameters Routing

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I'm having a problem in getting the output of the "match" object value in this parameter routing code.

This is class where I use match:

```
import React from "react";

const ProductDetails = (props) => {
  console.log(props.match);
  return <h1>Details No. </h1>;
};

export default ProductDetails;
```

And the code I use for using the route is:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import NavBar from "./navbar";
import ProductDetails from "./productDetails";

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <NavBar
          productsCount={this.state.Product.filter((p) => p.count > 0).length}
        />
        <main className="container">
          <Routes>
            <Route path="/about" element={<About />} />
            <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
            <Route path="/contact" element={<Contact />} />
            <Route
              path="/cart"
              element={
                <ShoppingCart
                  products={this.state.Product}
                  onReset={this.resetData}
                  onIncrement={this.incrementEntry}
                  onDelete={this.deleteEntery}
                />
              }
            />
            <Route path="/products/:id" element={<ProductDetails />} />
          </Routes>
        </main>
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}
```

And I get the answer as "undefined" and a lot of red errors msgs.

Comment: are you using react router v5 or v6?

Comment: and what is `this.state`, `this.resetData`, ... seams it isn't defined anywhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you are using react router v6 and what you want to do is getting the id, it would be:

```js
import React from "react";

const ProductDetails = () => {
  const {id} = useParams();
  return <h1>Details No. {id}</h1>;
};

export default ProductDetails;
```

or if you really want the match object:

```js
import React from "react";

const ProductDetails = () => {
  const match = useMatch();
  return <h1>Details No.</h1>;
};

export default ProductDetails;
```

Comment: i think the problem i had was to useParam because the course i study from appears to be an old version so it used props.match.params immediate ........... but when i used useMatch it gave me this issue

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'path')
    at matchPath (index.tsx:1079)
    at useMatch (index.tsx:434)

Comment: what is the exact result you expect, so what do you want to get? the current route path? current location?

Comment: https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/api#matchpath

Answer (score 0):

What is element? If you use react-router-dom for routing you must set the component for any route.

```
<BrowserRouter>
    <Route path ="/about" component= {<About />} />
    <Route path ="/" component= {<Home/>}/>
    <Route path ="/contact" component= {<Contact/>}/>
    <Route path ="/cart" component= {<ShoppingCart 
        products= {this.state.Product}
        onReset ={this.resetData}
        onIncrement ={this.incrementEntry} 
        onDelete = {this.deleteEntery}/>}/>
    <Route path="/products/:id" component={<ProductDetails />}/>
</BrowserRouter>
```

Comment: react_devtools_backend.js:2540 Matched leaf route at location "/about" does not have an element. This means it will render an <Outlet /> with a null value by default resulting in an "empty" page. 
    at Routes (http://localhost:3000/static/js/vendors~main.chunk.js:33026:5)
    at main
    at App (http://localhost:3000/main.9c5877b741bd285f91c7.hot-update.js:39:5)
    at Router (http://localhost:3000/static/js/vendors~main.chunk.js:32959:15)
    at BrowserRouter (http://localhost:3000/static/js/vendors~main.chunk.js:32474:5)

Comment: @AbdelrahmanKamal the docs say to use `component={About}` not `component={<About/>}`

Comment: whenever i use the component i never access the other class for ex if  i used a component on /about  it shows an error like the one upove and i still begining to learn react so the element was the solution i found after searching

Comment: i get the same error when making it    {About}